# Convert all french accents into HTML character format

Tags: html, non-ascii-characters, iconv, recode, french

I have for example a bunch of HTML pages like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Table des matières</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"" />
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<!-- 3,html,xhtml,charset="utf-8" -->
<meta name="src" content="content_final.tex" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content_final.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
$('div.caption span.id').each(function() { var result = $(this).text().replace(':','');
result=capitalizeFirstLetter(result);
$(this).text(result);
});
});
</script>
</head><body
>
<!--l. 125--><div class="crosslinks"><p class="noindent">[<a
href="chapter1.html" >next</a>] [<a
href="#tailcontent.html">tail</a>] [<a
href="/sciences/index.html" >up</a>] </p></div>
<h2 class="likechapterHead"><a
 id="x2-1000"></a>Table des matières</h2>
<div class="tableofcontents">
```

But impossible to convert all french accents in these HTML pages like above the accent in
"`Table des matières`" with "`è`" appearing instead of "`&egrave;`".

I tried 2 things :

1. `for i in $(ls *.html); do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 $i > $i"_new"; mv -f $i"_new" $i; done`

=> the accents are not converted

2. `for i in $(ls *.html); do recode ..html $i; done`

=> I have the following errors :

```
recode: section5.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
recode: section6.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
recode: section7.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
recode: section8.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
recode: section9.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
recode: table_of_contents.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
...
```

I don't know what to do to convert all these french accents ?

Has anyone got an idea or suggestion to convert all possible french accents ? I would like to use `iconv`, `recode` or `sed` commands.

**UPDATE 1:** taking a basic example, here is the message I get for a single file :

```
$ recode ..html table_of_contents.html
recode: table_of_contents.html failed: Invalid input in step `CHAR..ISO-10646-UCS-2'
```

What's wrong ?

**UPDATE 2:** here is the output of my original HTML pages :

`$file -i index.html`

`$ index.html: text/x-tex; charset=iso-8859-1`

and the head of the `index.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Table des matières</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"" />
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<!-- 3,html,xhtml,charset="utf-8" -->
<meta name="src" content="content_final.tex" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content_final.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
$('div.caption span.id').each(function() { var result = $(this).text().replace(':','');
result=capitalizeFirstLetter(result);
$(this).text(result);
```

If I apply the command :

```
$ recode -vfd u8..html index.html

Request: UTF-8..:libiconv:..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Shrunk to: UTF-8..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Recoding index.html... done
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Table des matires</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"" />
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" />
<!-- 3,html,xhtml,charset="utf-8" -->
<meta name="src" content="content_final.tex" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content_final.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
$('div.caption span.id').each(function() { var result = $(this).text().replace(':','');
result=capitalizeFirstLetter(result);
$(this).text(result);
});
});
</script>
```

as you can see, the "`è`" has disappeared.

What can I do ?

Comment: This looks like a common problem. Have you checked here https://askubuntu.com/questions/40047/tool-to-convert-accented-characters-to-html-entities? Before trying for a whole file, have you tried a minimal example, such as a file with only one character in it, an è for example?

Comment: That's an HTML entity, it doesn't have anything to do with UTF-8. In fact the page declares to be using UTF-8 (not sure why you think it's ISO-8859-1). So... You basically try to make your page compatible with US-ASCII? What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález . I want to convert "é" as "&eacute;", "è" as "&egrave;", "à" as "&agrave;" and all the french accents and I would  like to avoid using `sed` since there are a lot of possible accents, I would like to perform it using `recode` or `iconv`

Comment: @geco17 . Yes I saw this post, that's why I tried in my post above the command `recode ..html $i` but it doesn't seem to work, the character "`é`" is not converted.

Comment: Is there any problem to solve or it's just for aesthetics?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález there is really a problem to solve it, it is not for aesthetics.

Comment: Why is it a problem? Why do you think you need to convert the characters to HTML entities? If the characters are encoded properly (preferably UTF-8) *and* the web server is configured to send the correct `Content-Type` header, then those characters will work fine.

Comment: @RoToRa . I don't know why it doesn't work despite of all you have said. Please try to find a "magic command" which converts all these accents, I would be grateful. Regards

Comment: We are not asking why it won't work. We are asking why you want to do the conversion in the first place.

Comment: @RoToRa . since all the other pages of my website respects this format and I would like these HTML pages to have the same convention

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want using recode. If it was me I would write a PHP script to run from the command line.  Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the source file encoding is UTF-8. Following command worked in my environment:

```
$ recode -vfd u8..html index.html
```

Output:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8

$ file -i index.html
index.html: text/html; charset=utf-8

$ recode -vfd u8..html index.html
Request: UTF-8..:iconv:..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Shrunk to: UTF-8..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Recoding index.html... done
```

You can use the command options to debug the error in this way:

- `-v` Verbose output. Useful to find in which step the error occurred.
- `-f` Forces the completion even if error occurred. You can [compare](https://text-compare.com) the output file with original to figure out which character/location is giving trouble.
- `-d` For HTML, recode doesn't convert ASCII characters. Avoids conversion of `< > " &` etc. html characters.

---

**Update** If the encoding/charset is `iso-8859-1` then you need to use:

```
$ recode -vfd iso-8859-1..html index.html
Request: ISO-8859-1..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Recoding index.html... done

#Or use following. 

$ recode -vfd lat1..html index.html
Request: ISO-8859-1..ISO-10646-UCS-2..HTML_4.0
Recoding index.html... done
```

The `ISO-8859-1` has following aliases in recode:

```
l1 
lat1
latin1
Latin-1
819/CR-LF 
CP819/CR-LF 
CSISOLATIN1 
IBM819/CR-LF 
ISO8859-1 
iso-ir-100 
ISO_8859-1 
ISO_8859-1:1987
```

You can use anyone of the above in the command.

Comment: here is the output of my original HTML pages : `$file -i index.html` 

`$ index.html: text/x-tex; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: For `iso-8859-1` you can use command `recode -vfd lat1..html index.html`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah ! I got it ! . Thanks a lot.